# Are there instructions for installing Kivy on cygwin?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, ctypes, kivy

I'm failing in running the following *hello world* on Kivy:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World!')

if __name__=="__main__":
    HelloApp().run()
```

with the following errors:

```
$ python hello1.py 
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/Administrator/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-10-28_1.txt
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "hello1.py", line 5, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/home/rbarakx/python/kivy/kivy/app.py", line 321, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/home/rbarakx/python/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 28, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "/home/rbarakx/python/kivy/kivy/clock.py", line 177, in <module>
     _kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'
$
```

I suspect my Kivy cygwin's installation may be lacking.

**Are there instructions for installing *Kivy* on *cygwin*?**
(googling the usual suspects did not produce any results)

Comment: I've never seen such instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What fixed the situation?

1. Prior to installing `Kivy,` installing `Cython` and `pygame` with `pip` in Cygwin's Python 2.7
2. Start Cygwin's X11 using `startxwin`
3. Define $DISPLAY with `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests you encountered [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/issues/detail?id=164) where cygwin's python is compiled with `os.name = posix`. You may end up having to recompile it yourself... Alternatively maybe you could use MinGW instead, as documented [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Creating-a-64-bit-development-environment-with-MinGW-on-Windows), or simply use the [native Windows version](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html).

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, I'll investigate your lead.